# How output values each 1 second?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
void _f1() {
  setState(() {
   //clear output
   _str = '';
  });
  for(int i=1; i<=5; i++) {
   Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
    setState(() {
     _str += '$i ';
    });
   });
  }
 }
```

Now **1 2 3 4 5** output all at once.

How output values  each 1 second? For example: 1 (passed 1 second), 2 (passed 1 second), 3 (passed 1 second), 4 (passed 1 second), 5 (passed 1 second) ? Thank you. Full code.

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
   debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   title: 'Name App',
   theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
   ),
   home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
     title: Text('Name Page'),
    ),
    body: MyHomePage(),
   ),
  );
 }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 String _str;

 @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _str = '';
 }

 void _f1() {
  setState(() {
   //clear output
   _str = '';
  });
  for(int i=1; i<=5; i++) {
   Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
    setState(() {
     _str += '$i ';
    });
   });
  }
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Stack(
   children: <Widget>[
    Align(
     alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
     child: Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 45.0,
      //color: Colors.pink,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: FlatButton(
       onPressed: () {
        _f1();
       },
       color: Colors.black12,
       shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
       ),
       child: Text(
        'ok',
        style: TextStyle(
         color: Colors.deepPurple,
         fontSize: 22.0,
        ),
       ),
      ),
     ),
    ),
    Align(
     alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
     child: Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Text(
       _str,
       style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.red,
        fontSize: 36.0,
       ),
      ),
     ),
    ),
   ],
  );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To output a command every second, try this example function:

```
void countSeconds(s) {
  for( var i = 1 ; i <= s; i++ ) {
      Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: i), () => print(i));
   }
}
```

Extracted from [here.](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#example-execution-within-async-functions)

Adapting to your case, we can have:

```
void _f1() {
  setState(() {
   //clear output
   _str = '';
  });
  for(int i=1; i<=5; i++) {
   Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: i), () {
    setState(() {
     _str += '$i ';
    });
   });
  }
 }
```

The key difference here is that you were setting 5 `future.delayed` at *the same time* (Ok, maybe a few milliseconds from each other) so they all ended up at roughly the same time. So the fix is to set from the start futures to every desired duration, and not to try to set "concatenated" futures.

Comment: Dear Naslausky! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with **Timer.periodic**

```
class OutputOneByOne extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OutputOneByOneState createState() => _OutputOneByOneState();
}

class _OutputOneByOneState extends State<OutputOneByOne> {

  int counter = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Text("$counter"),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: startTimer,
      ),
    );
  }

  void startTimer(){
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        counter++;
        if(counter == 5){
          timer.cancel();
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Dear Josteve Adekanbi! Thank you very much!